# Is there way to close popup when swiping between tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a popup menu in one tab which not close automatically between swiping from tab to tab. Clicking outside of the popup window closing it, but the swipe is not detected as click so the popup stays on the screen as long as I click outside of it.

Have Googled this issue for a couple hours now with no results.

Can you give me any glue how handle this problem? I want that popup close when swipe, but don't know how.

Comment: Can you add code snippets pls ?

Comment: Let us know what you've written. Edit your question and insert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `id="somethinghere"` for the tab, and for the popup menu element I added `attach="somethinghere"`. Now it is attached to one tab and not following to other tabs, but it is not still closing. But this is better than nothing.